# Write junit for JPA repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, spring-orm

Hi I need to write junit test cases for JPA repository. Code is as below.

Test is written as below. I have already added @ContextConfiguration on the class.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("repository")
private Repository repository;

@Test
public void testCreate() {
    Object objRequest = getObjForRequest();
    Object obj = repository.create(objRequest);
    assertTrue(obj.getId().equals(objRequest.getId()));
}

private Object getObjForRequest() {
    Object obj = new Object();

    obj.setId(1);

    return obj;
}
```

My Repository is written as below.

```
@Repository("repository")
public class Repository implements RepositoryInterface {

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;

      @Transactional(value = "springJpaTransactionManager")
      @Override
      public Object create(Object obj) {
             Object ob = obj;
             entityManager.persist(ob);
             entityManager.flush();
             return ob;
      }
}
```

When I am running test case it is giving me below error.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:com.*.*.Object
```

Can anybody help me resolving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove setId from :

```
private Object getObjForRequest() {
    Object obj = new Object();    
    obj.setId(1);    
    return obj;
}
```

you shouldn't set id , as id generated when object become persisted id DB. When you call repository.create(objRequest) with id , spring data do check what it should be - creation new object or update existed , and this check is based on id!=null;

you should check :

```
   assertNoNull(obj.getId());
   assertTrue(obj.getId().longValue()>0);
```

you can compare that id as expected only where you update some existed entity.